# How do I run a gawk file with spaces in the path name?

Tags: file, command-line, awk, space, gawk

I am trying to run the following line in an awk script and I am getting an error.  I think the error is because the filename has spaces in it.  How do I call the file without changing the path name (i.e. rename the file/path)?  The code is contain within a BEGIN{} block.

```
INSTALLATION_LOCATION_GAWK = "L:/CPU_Analysis/Sanity/CPUAnalysisApp/cpu_analysis_application/"
DATA_SUMMARY_LOCATION_GAWK = "C:/Program Files/CPU Analysis/data/data_summary.csv"
....
command = ("gawk -v version=" dataArray[1] " -v date=" dataArray[2] " -v platform=" dataArray[3] " -f ") (INSTALLATION_LOCATION_GAWK "generateSanity_Scripts/removeData.awk ") DATA_SUMMARY_LOCATION_GAWK
system(command)
```

**UPDATE:** I also ran into the issue that you cannot copy/save/edit files in C:\Program Files due to windows restrictions.  I solved this problem by moving my project to C:\My Programs.

Comment: It might be a good idea to not make us guess what error you are getting...

Comment: @twalberg - good point.  I will make sure to include the error in future questions.  The error I was getting was for an invalid file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* it will be a case of providing quotes in the command string:

```
command = "gawk"
command = command " -v version=\"" dataArray[1] "\""
command = command " -v date=\"" dataArray[2] "\""
command = command " -v platform=\"" dataArray[3] "\""
command = command " -f \"" INSTALLATION_LOCATION_GAWK "generateSanity_Scripts/removeData.awk\""
command = command " \"" DATA_SUMMARY_LOCATION_GAWK "\""
```

Comment: I put the command all on one line, but it was a case of including the quotes.  Thank you!